# Alternative to using WHERE ... IN (...) for slow SQL queries

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sorting

This is actually part of a much larger complex query.
According to the query plan the sort on this statement dominates the cost of the larger query.
And by materializing this part of the query I verified it dominates the cost.

```
    select [sID], ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [sID] order by [wordPos]) [rn], [wordPos], [wordID]
      from [FTSindex] 
     where [wordID] in (428,2112)
  order by [sID], [rn]
```

From right to left:
- Index seek 5% (IX_FTSindex_wordID_sID)
- Sort  76%
- Parallelism 19%

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FTSindex](
    [sID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordPos] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [charPos] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FTSindex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [sID] ASC,
    [wordPos] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FTSindex_wordID_sID] ON [dbo].[FTSindex] 
(
    [wordID] ASC,
    [sID] ASC,
    [wordPos] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Given the IX_FTSindex_wordID_sID includes [sID] and [wordPos] I thought that sort would be very fast.
Tried [wordID] alone and [wordID], [sID] and still the sort is still 76% of the cost.

Even this query

```
    select [sID], [wordPos] -- , wordID
      from [FTSindex] 
     where [wordID] in (428,2112)
  order by [sID], [wordPos]
```

The sort is sort is 76% or the cost.

How can I get the sort cost to come down?
The PK has to stay as it is.
I can add or revise other indexes.

Comment: `IX_FTSindex_wordID_sID` sounds good, but since you are searching for more than one value of `wordID` you are likely to get a pile of rows that need to be sorted on `sID` and `wordPos`.  The index only has them in order for _each_ value of `wordID`.  My gut feeling is that you aren't going to win this one.  Just for grins, can you query for each `wordID` separately and then `UNION` the results, perhaps with a `MERGE UNION` hint?  (The hope being that a merge sort would be faster since you know the two sets are already sorted.)  Are the statistics current?  How large are the sets involved?

Comment: 900 million rows.  Union then sort on the union is is slower by 20%.  Merge hint had no effect.

Comment: Are you saying there are 900 million total rows in the table or in the result set of your query?

Comment: Did you do a UNION or a UNION ALL? UNION alone forces a sort in order to eliminate duplicates, while UNION ALL doesn't.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Union All.

Comment: @brandon 900 million is the table size.  The result is like 1.6 million rows.

Comment: I have suggested a title that may help future readers find this question. Please review.

Comment: It looks like someone already changed the title.  There is a user on SO that insists an in is always faster than a join.

Comment: That was me. ;-)  I have never encountered a situation, using SQL Server, where IN is **faster** than a join; at best the same. I cannot speak for other SQL engines.

Comment: Gets a vote to close and yet an answer with 3 up votes.  How is optimizing a specific query not a specific programming question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for giggles again, could you try this query:

```
  select 
    [sID], 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [sID] order by [wordPos]) [rn], 
    [wordPos], [FTSindex].[wordID]
  from [FTSindex] 
  join ( 
    values (428), (2112)
  ) w (wordID) on w.wordID = [FTSindex].wordID
  order by [sID], [rn]
```

Sometimes, throwing more hardware at the problem is the correct answer; though I agree that this should be a last resort and not a first. Whether this particular problem requires more CPU, more memory, or more spindles is dependent on many factors, including your present hardware.

Your result set of 1.6 million rows, each 4 integers, should sort quickly on any reasonable amount of current hardware. Since delays are occurring it seems likely that too much processing is occurring on the base set of 900 million rows, and the challenge is to identify why.  Can you attach more details about the query plan?

Comment: That was more than giggles.   It worked.  One minor syntax error I edited.  And I did not know you could hard code join values like that +1.