# Slow SQL query execution time with inner joins

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit).

My query execution time is about 1 min.

- `Docum` table has xxxxxxxx rows
- `Pers` table has xxxxxxx rows
- `Permarks` table has xxxxxx rows

Indexes on the `Docum` table:

[image]

Indexes on the `Pers` table:

Indexes on the `Permarks` table:

```
PERSMARKS_pm_p_id   
PERSON_MARKScode_AND_date_till_AND_end_date_
```

Query:

```
SELECT doc
FROM docum(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN pers(NOLOCK) ON doc = p
INNER JOIN permarks(NOLOCK) ON pm = p
WHERE doccode IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30) 
  AND pm_ = 14
  AND (enddate IS NULL OR enddate > getdate())
  AND (date_till IS NULL OR date_till > getdate())
```

How can I speed up this query?

Here is full query, execution time is 5 minutes INTO #temp:

```
SELECT f
    ,0 AS viso
    ,count(DISTINCT p) AS el_budu
    ,0 AS vidinis
    ,0 AS pasirasyta
    INTO #temp
FROM documents(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN fo(NOLOCK) ON doc = fv
INNER JOIN for(NOLOCK) ON fve = f
INNER JOIN per(NOLOCK) ON doc = p
INNER JOIN tax ti(NOLOCK) ON p = ti
INNER JOIN permarks(NOLOCK) ON pm = p
WHERE pmtcode = 14
    AND (
        enddate IS NULL
        OR enddate > getdate()
        )
    AND (
        datetill IS NULL
        OR datetill > getdate()
        )
    AND startdate >= '2015-01-01'
    AND enddate <= '2015-12-31'
    AND rtcode = 1
    AND fvcode IN (25)
    AND doccode IN (
        20
        ,21
        ,22
        ,23
        ,24
        ,25
        ,30
        )
GROUP BY fcode
```

execution plan results: [results photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LozVj.png)

Comment: Do you have index in doc_dprt_code?

Comment: yes, i have non-clustered index off two columns doc_dprt_code and doc_reg_date

Comment: You should review an `execution plan`. Bad filters on dates by the way.

Comment: I suggest you look at the execution plan to see which part is expensive.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, why the filter on date is bad?

Comment: I know, but I don't have permission

Comment: What indices to you have on the tables in the queries? Edit your question to supply this information.

Comment: It's impossible not to have permissions to view execution plan unless you have no access to db/server at all (mean - to developer with appropriate permissions).

Comment: i get this error Msg 262, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
SHOWPLAN permission denied in database '1111'.

Comment: Are you attempting to execute a bigger script with DDL commands?

Comment: no, i executing query in ms sql server management studio

Comment: Is this a full text of query you are executing in ssms? Or just a `select` part of it?

Comment: There are few things to optimize here,Like Filtering on dates,using alternative for In clause
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878465/alternative-to-using-where-in-for-slow-sql-queries/16884643#16884643   overall your Table defination,normalization,indeces helps a lot in query exectuiton time

Comment: yes its full that i am executing

Comment: That's strange. Ask then your DBA for plan.

Comment: By the way, how many rows does it finally return?

Comment: 2808667 rows it return, it is really don't normal that its executing 1-2 min.?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say. Scripts can work for hours and days. You should also realize that regardless **execution** time there is also **delivery** time and time to display. Could be that most of 2 minutes SSMS is "downloading" those 3M records.

Comment: Try executing this query with `INSERT INTO #Temp` or `SELECT INTO #Temp`. That would be the actual query execution time on the server. I suspect network latency in returning all this data to the client machine

Comment: there is the almost same select only one where part different  doc_dprt_code IN (30)  and it executing in 1 second , does its normal?

Comment: You need to get the execution plan. If you've been tasked to fix this then you need to ask someone for sufficient permission to fix it.

Comment: i get key look up on clustered index on documents table, what i need to do?

Comment: Stop vandalizing your questions...

Comment: apologies but I chose to rollback, not sure if I got the best variant, but somehow the question was getting way off track

Comment: Which table(s) do `f_legal_code` and `p_legal_code` come from? in fact for the second query which tables do all the columns come from? **always** prefix the columns by their table name or table alias, if you did this I would not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the image above I have marked columns with clustered/nonclustered index. Correct me if there is anything wrong written in the above image. My points are as below : -

1. Do you have any clustered index in table documents and person_marks. It seems that there are all nonclustered indexes on them. If there is no clustered index then nonclustered index have to fetch values from the table which is expensive and you will not get good execution plan.
2. Make clustered index on pm_p_id and doc_p_id if possible if values are unique. This will help optimizer to use merge join instead of hash join.
3. Make use of #temp table

Comment: 1.Yes i have clustered index in these tables

Answer (score 0):

I re-structured your query for my readability.  I also added
aliases as they APPEAR to be represented in your tables which
should be a good habit to get into, especially for anyone who
has to follow / work with you and learning where data actually
comes from without having to ask for table structures.

You are joining to the persons table, but not really using anything
ON the person's record with exception of the "p_id" to join to
the person_marks table.

```
SELECT 
      d.doc_p_id
   FROM 
      documents d (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN persons p (NOLOCK) 
            ON d.doc_p_id = p.p_id
            INNER JOIN person_marks pm (NOLOCK) 
               ON p.p_id = pm.pm_p_id 
              AND pm.pm_pmt_code = 14
              AND (pm.pm_end_date IS NULL OR pm.pm_end_date > getdate())
              AND (pm.pm_date_till IS NULL OR pm.pm_date_till > getdate())
   WHERE 
      d.doc_dprt_code IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30)
```

Via transitive process, If the documents "doc_p_id" is the person
ID, then that can be used to directly go to the person_marks table
without joining persons removing that completely from the mix 
(unless this was just a sample and you will be grabbing personal
information later for production query).

```
SELECT 
      d.doc_p_id
   FROM 
      documents d (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN person_marks pm (NOLOCK) 
            ON d.doc_p_id = pm.pm_p_id 
           AND pm.pm_pmt_code = 14
           AND (pm.pm_end_date IS NULL OR pm.pm_end_date > getdate())
           AND (pm.pm_date_till IS NULL OR pm.pm_date_till > getdate())
   WHERE 
      d.doc_dprt_code IN (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30)
```

Next, for indexing, I would recommend the following table/indexes
to be covering indexes for the query criteria so it does not have
to go to the actual data pages to resolve entries.

```
table          index
documents      ( doc_dprt_code, doc_p_id )
person_marks   ( pm_p_id, pm_pmt_code, pm_end_date, pm_date_till )
```

Finally, since you are (at present), only grabbing the person ID, you might want to change to

```
select DISTINCT d.doc_p_id ...
```

So it only returns one record per person (again, unless you are actually grabbing other data and just simplifying the query for post/support purposes).

Comment: yes it is a sample, i need persons table to get p_legal_count, all index is existing